# MySQL rows with maximum and specific values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to write a query to retrieve data from a table, using the selected date and selected category. I have written a query and it does not give correct data as expected. It should query only rows with maximum `actiondate`, if the `action` column has the value `'AD'`.

```
INSERT INTO goldstockvaluation SELECT sh.stockid, sh.description, sh.branch, sh.grossweight, sh.pureweight, sh.purity, sh.goldcarat, sh.mcpergram, sh.goldpergram, sh.fixgold, CURDATE( )
FROM stock_history sh
JOIN (

SELECT stockid, branch,ACTION , MAX( actiondate ) AS MaxDateTime
FROM stock_history
GROUP BY stockid,branch,ACTION 
)groupedsh ON sh.stockid = groupedsh.stockid
AND sh.actiondate = groupedsh.MaxDateTime
AND sh.branch = groupedsh.branch
AND sh.action = groupedsh.action 
AND sh.branch = '8'
AND sh.categoryid = 'G'
AND sh.action = 'AD'
AND sh.actiondate <= '2016-03-28 23:59:59'
```

This is to query out the rows that have `action` as `'AD'` and have the `max(actiondate)`.

Comment: What is the primary key? Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE stock_history` and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

To query with `max(action_date)`, you need to use sub query, e.g.:

```
select field1, field2
from table
where 
sh.action = 'AD'
and sh.actiondate = (
    select max(sh.actiondate)
        from table 
        where sh.action = 'AD'
);
```

Comment: The MAX actiondate should be less than selected date and should return only if the max entry values has 'AD' in it.

Comment: I explained how to query when it includes comparison with `max` value of any field. You can add the conditions as and when needed.

Comment: This will return only one row. OP needs one row per group (`GROUP BY stockid,branch,ACTION`)

Comment: We can use this condition in `HAVING` clause along with `group by`if we want one row per group.